# Regex "reluctant" quantifier misbehaves

Tags: java, regex

I've got this Java code, part of a LaTex songbook project.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\retitle\\{(.*?)\\}",Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
System.out.println(m.matches());
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Given this input:

```
\retitle{Livin' on a prayer}{Bon Jovi}
\begin{song}\begin{vers}[Em]Johnie used to work on the docks\newline
Saving up his money I don't know these l[C]yrics\newline
l[D]ol.\newline
\end{vers}
\end{song}
```

I'm expecting this output:

```
true
Livin' on a prayer
```

But I actually get this:

```
true
Livin' on a prayer}{Bon Jovi}
\begin{song}\begin{vers}[Em]Johnie used to work on the docks\newline
Saving up his money I don't know these l[C]yrics\newline
l[D]ol.\newline
\end{vers}
\end{song
```

In other words, the `*?` quantifier is not as "reluctant" as I expect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `m.end(1)` return?

Comment: As you can see here (http://regex101.com/r/qC7hZ7) there is no problem with you regex, but rather your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not in your regex, but in the method you're using: `Matcher.matches()` tries to match the pattern against the *entire* input. The reluctance of the quantifier doesn't really get a chance to be relevant, because your input-string can match the pattern in only one way.

Instead, you need to use `Matcher.find()`, which tries to find a substring of the input that matches the pattern.

See [the Javadoc for `Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for more information.

Comment: In this particular case, does the regex engine automatically replace the reluctant quantifier with a greedy quantifier before processing the string? (like an internal optimisation)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I doubt it. Keep in mind that reluctant quantifiers are not *inherently* meaningless with `matches`; something like `(.*?)x(.*?)` can give different results than something like `(.*)x(.*)`, since in `(.*?)x(.*?)` the `x` gets matched to the *first* `x` in the string, whereas in `(.*)x(.*)` the `x` gets matched to the *last* `x` in the string. So the regex engine would have to really analyze the regex to determine whether that optimization is safe. My experience with JDK regexes has been that they're nowhere near that clever.

Comment: Indeed, with this kind of pattern, the optimization is not obvious. (except if the optimization is on the last quantifier only, and not sure that you will gain something)